# How to make algorithm to add numbers to make equal or greater than required

Tags: php

Situation, customer chooses to pay for purchases using SMS messages, he buys for 15 euros.
Algorithm have to find how much messages and for what price customer needs to send to pay for purchases.
The cost should be as less as possible for the customer.
I have json file with sms list prices and income.

And here is what i have so far written

```
<?php

$input = file_get_contents("input.json");

$json = json_decode($input, true);

$required_income = $json['required_income'];
$sms = array();
$index = 0;
$suma = 0;

function imoka($suma, $json, &$index, &$sms) {

    for($i = 3; $i >= 0; $i--){
        if($suma + $json['sms_list'][$i]['income'] <= $json['required_income']) {
            $sms[$index] = $json['sms_list'][$i]['income'];
            $index = $index + 1;
            return imoka($suma + $json['sms_list'][$i]['income'], $json, $index, $sms);
        }
    }
}

imoka($suma, $json, $index, $sms);

for($i = 0; $i < $index; $i++){
    echo $sms[$i] . '<br>';
}

?>
```

The problem is what this algorithm gets just less than 15, and task ask to go 15 or a litle bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change the required income to

```
$required_income = $json['required_income']+.4;
```

because it will at last still add the minimal value.

Comment: tried that, it works, but when you change required income it doesn't work. For example if required income will be 2.9 customer will have to pay 2.9 and .41 euros

Comment: Try to change the <= operator to < in your if clause

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Vitas This isn't really right at all ,you are calculating income without taking the price in case , as I can see the problem over here is the customer should get the highest income with lowest cost which you are not doing you are just getting the first income >= 15 .

Comment: Income is how much money company gets after network takes it share. Price is how much sms going to cost for customer

Comment: so do you care about price or not ?

Comment: Price will be only showed for user, so it goes to sms array. But overall in algorithm it makes no role. The only thing that cares is that income should be equal or greater than required income

Comment: @Vitas why didn't you take required income / maximum income  to determine the number of sms you wants to get instead of such complex code i.e you would have only two cases required_income % maximum_income  == 0 or required_income % maximum income  != 0 in the first case you would take the price of the maximum_income ( required_income / maximum_income ) times and in the second case you would  take the price of the maximum_income ( required_income / maximum_income ) times + price of minimum_income only one time instead of doing recursion and all of this :)

Comment: It is for my work that means I have to work with that what they gave to me and I cant add new values to task